# How to get a smaller piece-wise linear curve between two?

Tags: algorithm, piecewise

I have two piece-wise linear curves c1 & c2, and I want a new piece-wise linear curve c3 being the smaller parts of c1 and c2.

Is there a neat algorithm to get the c3?

their points are:

```
C1          C2          C3  
0   1       0   1.5     0   1
1   1       2   1.5     1   1
2   2       3.5 3       1.5 1.5
3   2       4   3       2   1.5
3   3       4   3.5     2.5 2
4   3       5   3.5     3   2
4   4                   3   2.5
5   4                   3.5 3
                        4   3
                        4   3.5
                        5   3.5
```

[image]

Comment: Your question can't be answered as it stands. Take a look at the two points of C3 at position x=3. Only one of them should be part of the curve, as it is "smaller" than the other. You will have to define more precisely what you mean.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, aside from using “smaller” where the word  “minimum” might be more appropriate, the spec isn't ambiguous; only certain points can be selected and still follow one or the other of the two input curves

Comment: Hi Ulrich and jwpat7, my question was not precisely defined, but the picture shows what the c3 should be: the minimum part of either c1 or c2.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following approach to determine the curve. This curve would form the border of an area that is otherwise limited by x=[0, 5] and open towards negative Y values. I'm assuming that there are no loops or backward curves in the input.

Following steps:

1. Normalize the size of the two curves: They both should have the same number of segments that use the the same upper and lower X positions, which you achieve by interpolating and inserting additional points. Using the same number of points and the same X positions doesn't work since there are sometimes multiple points at the same X position. This can mean that a segment of one normalize curve is defined by two equal points, but this is important for e.g. position x=3 and it makes overall thinking and debugging easier.
2. Determine intersections: Whenever the order of the Y position (whether C1 or C2 is below)  changes within a segment, there must be an intersection between the two lines. Determine this point and replace the segments in each curve with two segments. Running this step a second time should not insert additional points and yield the same number of points in C1 and C2 still.
3. Form the third curve by picking the point with the lowest Y position from each index of points. Here you go back to thinking in single points, not segments, which is what the preparations above are necessary for.

Comment: Ulrich, than you very much for your advice, I will try it and let you know the results!